# php password_hash generated through $.ajax invalid

Tags: php, sql, ajax, password-hash

I set up a simple ajax request to a php file to get a password_hash.  We will be manually entering a few admin users, kind of a test project for me, but i still want to have a hash string in the database to validate their login.  I understand this is not the best way to go about this, but it is something i ran across and do not understand why.  There seems to be a little confusion, so here it is again. I have a web page that you enter a password into an input field, hit submit and the ajax call posts to the php server and converts the password to the hash and returns the hash, then I display it on the browser page.  I then take that hash, copy it from the browser and paste it into the database for that user.

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    var pw = $('#js-pw').val();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "api/someplace/",
          data: {'pw': pw},
          datatype : "text/plain",
          contentType: "text/plain",
          success: success
        });
  });

 function success(data){
    $('#target').val(data);
    console.log(typeof data);//string
  }
```

On the server "api/someplace"

```
$json = $app->request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$password = $data['pw'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//return the value to the ajax request
echo $hash; //$2y$10$g4Tir9D.VGiTdYPk7osST.ddzJvFRmw3PXiJ4g3qTLDSti3AqdstG
```

I take this returned hash string from the ajax request and manually add it to the users database record.  But when i try to validate the the actual login through another ajax call comparing the users entered password with the db password hash i get 'Invalid password' every time

```
if (password_verify($pword, $hashedPassword)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

The real kicker is when i use a hard coded file (somepage.php) to generate the hash(like below) I can copy this string from the browser and paste it in the database record and password_verify will return "Password is Valid"

```
$hash=password_hash("somepassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hash;
```

Any ideas on why the hash generated via ajax would fail and the hash generated via .php would pass?  Is there some encoding step I am missing? Does the copy and paste from the browser to mysql have anything to do with it?

Comment: `$data['pw']`? Are you sure it's `data` and not `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: If pasting the hash directly into the database works, why isn't this working? I doubt it's the AJAX request, it seems more like the process you're using to update the database with the hash in the first place? How are you adding the hash to the database with this AJAX? Also, why would the hash string ever ever return to the front-end? Why not save it to the database and return success or failure?

Comment: Try `console.log(data);` to check the returned value from PHP, and make sure it matches what's in the database.

Comment: Also, full contents of the code that generates the hash and stores it in the database would be helpful.

Comment: This is a tool to generate a hash key and I then manually copy and paste it into the database for that user, I am not setting any ground breaking procedures here, it is just something I came across.  The users do not set up an account, it is an internal tool that they would tell me the password and user name and I would add them to the database, so as to not directly add their password i made a page to turn their password into the hash string and i use that in the db

Comment: Is your database field big enough, it requires at least `varchar(60)` but better would be `varchar(255)` to be future proof.

Comment: Yes the db field is varchar(255)